# Using SSHFS to Mount Remote File Systems Over SSH, but no write permissions on mounted files

Tags: permissions, mount, ssh, sshfs

I am using SSHFS to mount some files from a debian machine to my laptop which runs ubuntu 16.

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,port=2222,default_permissions,nonempty,IdentityFile=home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa alex@hostsIP:/home/alex /home/alex/repos/
```

The user on the host machine happens to be the same as the one on my laptop. 
Anyway, i get the files mounted but not permitted to write. 
I assumed that since I got the mount done by ssh and used the ssh key , would grand me permissions just like working directly on the host machine via ssh.

Comment: It turns out that , adding "idmap=user" and removing default_permissions, fixes this problem. Some description can be fount here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? SSHFS works fine as a normal user.

Comment: yes , you are correct, works just fine as a normal user